# Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно вывести порядковый номер input type= radio на экран <p id="number-input"></p>

Tags: javascript, html

если  присвоить id к input и вывести его в id="number-input"

```js
function radioget(getValue) {
  document.getElementById('lblmess').innerText = getValue;
  let select = document.getElementById('list');
  showTotal(list.value);  
}

function showTotal(amount) {
  let product = document.querySelector('input[name="radioName"]:checked');
  let total = product ? (amount * product.value) : 0;
  document.getElementById('price').innerText = total;
}
```

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: "Bebas";
  font-style: none;
  src: local("Bebas"),url("/fonts/Bebas.ttf") format("ttf");
}



body{
    font-family: "Bebas", sans-serif; 
    font-size: 10px;
    color:color: #CFCFCF;
}



.total{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    width: 100px;
}

.form{
position: absolute;
width: 369px;
height: 386px;
background: #F8F8F8;
border: 10px solid #EBEBEB;
padding: 10px;
}

label{
    font-family: "Bebas", sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;

}

p{
   color:#B1B1B1;
}



.radioButton {
    display: flex;
     justify-content: space-between;
}


input{

} 

input:hover{
    border: 1px solid #CEE3EA;
    background-color: #FEFEFF;
} 

.of-licenes{ 
    display: flex;
     justify-content:center;
     margin: 15px;

}

.licenes_p{
    color: black;
    margin-right: 5px;
} 



.total-licenes{
     display: flex;
     justify-content:center;
     margin: 15px;
}


.total-p{ 
    font-size: 25px;
    color:#798BA0;
    margin: 0;
}

.total-price{
    font-size: 25px;
    color:#398BAA;
    margin: 0;
}

sup{
    color:#398BAA;
    font-size: 10px;
} 

.us{

    color:#398BAA;
    font-size: 25px;
    margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/main.js"></script>
        <title>test</title>
</head>
<body> 
    <div class="form">
 <div class="radioButton">
 <label><input type="radio" name="radioName" value="13"   onchange="radioget(this.value)" onchange="radioget(this.id)">licenseplan #1</label>
    <p>$13 &nbsp  per &nbsp license</p>
</div>
<div class="radioButton">
 <label><input type="radio" name="radioName" value="22"   onchange="radioget(this.value)">licenseplan #2</label>
     <p>$22 &nbsp  per &nbsp license</p>
</div>
<div class="radioButton">
 <label><input type="radio" name="radioName" value="34"  onchange="radioget(this.value)">licenseplan #3</label>
    <p>$34 &nbsp  per &nbsp license</p>
</div>
<hr/>
<div class="of-licenes">
    <p class="licenes_p">Namber of licenes</p> 
<select id="list" onchange="showTotal(this.value)">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>
    <option value="9">9</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
</select>
</div>
<hr/>
<div class="total-licenes">
    <p class="total-p">total:&nbsp</p><p class="us">&nbsp$</p><label id="price" class="total-price"></label><sup>US</sup>
</div>
<label id="lblmess"></label>
<p id="number-input"></p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: или как то можно исправить чтоб в id="lblmess" выводился а не значение value

Comment: Вообще не понятно что вам нужно

Answer (score 1):

Вы сами передаёте через атрибут `onchange="radioget(this.value)"`, вам нужно убрать `.value` и тогда вы будете обращаться прям к инпуту.

В примере я вывожу текст, который находится в родителе.

```js
function radioget(getValue) {
  document.getElementById('lblmess').innerText = getValue.closest('label').innerText;
  let select = document.getElementById('list');
  showTotal(list.value);  
}

function showTotal(amount) {
  let product = document.querySelector('input[name="radioName"]:checked');
  let total = product ? (amount * product.value) : 0;
  document.getElementById('price').innerText = total;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/main.js"></script>
        <title>test</title>
</head>
<body> 
    <div class="form">
 <div class="radioButton">
 <label><input type="radio" name="radioName" value="13"   onchange="radioget(this)" onchange="radioget(this.id)">licenseplan #1</label>
    <p>$13 &nbsp  per &nbsp license</p>
</div>
<div class="radioButton">
 <label><input type="radio" name="radioName" value="22"   onchange="radioget(this)">licenseplan #2</label>
     <p>$22 &nbsp  per &nbsp license</p>
</div>
<div class="radioButton">
 <label><input type="radio" name="radioName" value="34"  onchange="radioget(this)">licenseplan #3</label>
    <p>$34 &nbsp  per &nbsp license</p>
</div>
<hr/>
<div class="of-licenes">
    <p class="licenes_p">Namber of licenes</p> 
<select id="list" onchange="showTotal(this.value)">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>
    <option value="9">9</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
</select>
</div>
<hr/>
<div class="total-licenes">
    <p class="total-p">total:&nbsp</p><p class="us">&nbsp$</p><label id="price" class="total-price"></label><sup>US</sup>
</div>
<label id="lblmess"></label>
<p id="number-input"></p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

---

Если нужен порядковый номер, то проще всего его будет указать заранее через атрибут, допустим, `data-i`.

Например:

```js
function radioget(getValue) {
  document.getElementById('lblmess').innerText = getValue.getAttribute('data-i');
  let select = document.getElementById('list');
  showTotal(list.value);  
}

function showTotal(amount) {
  let product = document.querySelector('input[name="radioName"]:checked');
  let total = product ? (amount * product.value) : 0;
  document.getElementById('price').innerText = total;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/main.js"></script>
        <title>test</title>
</head>
<body> 
    <div class="form">
 <div class="radioButton">
 <label><input type="radio" name="radioName" value="13"   onchange="radioget(this)" onchange="radioget(this.id)" data-i="1">licenseplan #1</label>
    <p>$13 &nbsp  per &nbsp license</p>
</div>
<div class="radioButton">
 <label><input type="radio" name="radioName" value="22"   onchange="radioget(this)" data-i="2">licenseplan #2</label>
     <p>$22 &nbsp  per &nbsp license</p>
</div>
<div class="radioButton">
 <label><input type="radio" name="radioName" value="34"  onchange="radioget(this)" data-i="3">licenseplan #3</label>
    <p>$34 &nbsp  per &nbsp license</p>
</div>
<hr/>
<div class="of-licenes">
    <p class="licenes_p">Namber of licenes</p> 
<select id="list" onchange="showTotal(this.value)">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>
    <option value="9">9</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
</select>
</div>
<hr/>
<div class="total-licenes">
    <p class="total-p">total:&nbsp</p><p class="us">&nbsp$</p><label id="price" class="total-price"></label><sup>US</sup>
</div>
<label id="lblmess"></label>
<p id="number-input"></p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: а как вывести этот атрибут в <p id="number-input"></p>, я не могу убрать value от туда берутся даннны для вывода в total, мне нужно чтоб выводился номер активного инпута как это реализовано в <label id="lblmess"></label> только в label выводится value, возможно этот как то изменить?

Comment: Я не вижу чтобы при `onchange` вы где-то использовать `.value`, но вы можете внутри функции `radioget()` получать значение инпута, указав `getValue.value`

Comment: Не совсем понимаю....я редактировал впорос добавил css, если посмотрите, когда выбираю активный инпут выводится значение value в <label id="lblmess"></label>,  нужно что бы вместо это значние выводился номер инпута, но я решил попробывать отдельно пока вывести что бы ничего не сломать,  что бы выводилось  в <p id="number-input"></p>. вот в этом вопрос стоит....

Answer (score 0):

```
const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="radioName"]');
const numberInput = document.getElementById("number-input");

inputs.forEach((element, index)=>element.addEventListener('change', ()=>numberInput.innerText = index+1))
```

[codepen](https://codepen.io/bunakov94/pen/MWJvyMB)